# ASP.NET Core: [FromQuery] usage and URL format

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to use [FromQuery] in my web api and I am not sure how to use it.

Here's the GetAllBooks() method in the controller:

```
 [HttpGet]
 [Route("api/v1/ShelfID/{shelfID}/BookCollection")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllBooks(string shelfID, [FromQuery] Book bookinfo)
            {
               //do something
            }
```

Here's the Book model class:

```
 public class Book
    {
        public string ID{ get; set; }
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public string PublishDate { get; set; }
    }
```

I am confused about whether it is the correct way to use [FromQuery]. I thought the URL is

> `https://localhost:xxxxx/api/v1/ShelfID/{shelfID}/BookCollection/IActionResult?ID="123"&Name="HarryPotter"`

But the break point is not hitting my controller method, so I was thinking maybe the URL is not correct. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The name of the method and return type are completely ignored when you define your route explicitly via attributes like that. `IActionResult` shouldn't be there.

The correct URL would be: `https://localhost:xxxxx/api/v1/ShelfID/{shelfID}/BookCollection?ID="123"&Name="HarryPotter"`

Furthermore, query string binding only works out of the box for primitive types (string, int, etc). To bind a class to a query string you'd need a custom modelbinder, which is quite involved.

It would be better to just explicitly declare the properties you want to pass in:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllBooks(string shelfID,
                                             [FromQuery] string ID, 
                                             [FromQuery] string Name)
```

Comment: You can also use [FromQuery] to bind to complex object e.g. `public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery] MyFilterModel _filters)` Refer this link : http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/webapi/parameter-binding-in-web-api