# ASP.NET CORE 2.1 - FromQuery doesnt work?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have class for capturing all parameters :

```
public class UserParams
{
    private const int MaxPageSize = 50;
    public int PageNumber { get; set; } = 1;
    private int pageSize = 10;
    public int PageSize
    {
        get { return pageSize;}
        set { pageSize = (value > MaxPageSize) ? MaxPageSize : value;}
    }

    public int UserId { get; set; }        
    public string OrderBy { get; set; }
    public bool isAll {get; set;} = true; 
    public bool isManagers { get; set; } = false;
    public bool isPartners { get; set; } = false;
}
```

and my controllers:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUsers([FromQuery] UserParams userParams)
{
    var users = await _appRepo.GetUsers(userParams);
    var usersDto = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<UserSimpleDto>>(users);
    Response.AddPagination(users.CurrentPage, users.PageSize, users.TotalCount, users.TotalPages);
    return Ok(usersDto);
}
```

While my appRepo.GetUsers:

```
public async Task<PagedList<User>> GetUsers(UserParams userParams)
{
    var users = _context.Users.OrderByDescending(p => p.FirstName).AsQueryable();
    if(userParams.isManagers)
    {
        users = users.Where( u => u.IsManager == true);
    }

    if(userParams.isPartners)
    {
        users = users.Where( u => u.IsPartner == true);
    }

    return await PagedList<User>.CreateAsync(users, userParams.PageNumber, userParams.PageSize);
}
```

I tried to debug the code with Postman : 
http://localhost:5000/api/user?isManagers=1
or
http://localhost:5000/api/user?isManagers=true

but it seems the params isManagers still false (the result is still get all users)

How to fix this bug?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Core: \[FromQuery\] usage and URL format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49741284/asp-net-core-fromquery-usage-and-url-format)

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49741284/asp-net-core-fromquery-usage-and-url-format.  Basically, `FromQuery` only works with built-in primative types out of the box.  If you want to do what you have there, you need to make a custom model binder.

Comment: i saw example from udemy course where angular send data using httpclient and using httpparams for user params.

they catch the userparams in dotnet core using this way. but i have no idea how to test it using postman.

Comment: @nightingale2k1 your code works fine for me. Also, your method is called GetUsers, why do you use just 'user' in Postman calls?

Comment: @AlexRiabov because my controller: 
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class UserController : Controller

so everytime I call /api/user it will call method with HtttpGet altough I put name getUsers