# Adding [FromQuery] to Api Method solves swagger issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swagger-ui

I had issue when I tested my method with swagger and it says:

> Swagger TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with
>   GET/HEAD method cannot have body.

Now my method definition looks like this and everything works:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<ICollection<BasicReqDTO>>> GetTownsList([FromQuery]RequestObj request)
```

Note `[FromQuery]` there, and I'm wondering why it didnt worked when I had it like this (*Without `FromQuery`*):

```
public async Task<ActionResult<ICollection<BasicReqDTO>>> GetTownsList(RequestObj request)
```

What is point here?

I resolved this issue but I don't know why it had occured?

Thanks

Cheers

Comment: FromQuery is meant for complex types, like your collection of DTOs.  [See this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49741491/2779990)

Comment: I guess you're using `[ApiController]` in some form. That makes complex types default to `[FromBody]`, so adding `[FromQuery]` overrides that.

Comment: @KirkLarkin And could you please tell me something more about what's the difference if it's `[FromBody]` vs `[FromQuery]`, with some practical example.. what does that mean acctually in my scenario or any other similar scenario. Thanks Kirk :)

Comment: Start with the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2#sources), which describes the different attributes. Then you can ask more specific questions to get better help. :)