# 415 Unsupported Media Type in ASP.NET core web api

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to experiment with asp.net core web api so I made some simple api with a controller like this:

```csharp
[ApiController]
[Route("MyController")]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetResult")]
    public IActionResult GetResult(string param1, string param2= null, SomeClassObj obj = null)
    {  .... }
}
```

I ran the api locally and sent this postman GET request:

```
https://localhost:5001/MyController/GetResult?param1=someString
```

I got the error: 415 Unsupported Media Type

What am I missing here so it could work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Which version of .NET Core are you using?

Try doing the request from the browser and see if you have the same result.

Also, are you sure you're doing a GET and not a POST request in Postman? You shouldn't get 415 errors for GET requests, especially when you're not sending any body.
This error mainly occurs when you try to send a body and you haven't specified the media-type through the `Content-Type` header.

Ensure that the request is GET and your body is empty.

**Solution after post edit:**

As you're trying to parse a DTO object(`SomeClassObj`), you should specify where the values should come from. In order to fix your specific case, add the `[FromQuery]` attribute before `SomeClassObj`.

Your code should look like this:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("MyController")]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetResult")]
    public IActionResult GetResult(string param1, string param2= null, [FromQuery]SomeClassObj obj = null)
    {  .... }
}
```

This tells the parser to fetch the data from the query string. This will fix the `415` issue. However, if you want to bind to complex types, especially on get, checkout those topics: [ASP.NET CORE 3.1 Model Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#sources) and [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49741284/asp-net-core-fromquery-usage-and-url-format) as you will most probably encounter issues with parsing your DTO object.

Comment: .net core 3.1. In the postman it is a GET request and there is no body.

When copy pasted the same request to the browser I got again 415 error: type "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13"
title "Unsupported Media Type"
status 415
traceId "|f42c992c-498a76ef71e4af5e."

Comment: @YonatanNir You're missing something. Please, edit your initial post with the full code you're using in the controller. Also, just to be sure, attach a screenshot of the request you're doing in the browser and postman.

Comment: OK I apologize since I wrote here an old code. The signature of GetResult had an additional parameter which was not a string and its the one who caused it

Comment: Yep, most probably you're trying to use a DTO object. Update your initial post anyway so we can give you a proper solution.

Comment: edited. You can edit the response as well and I'll accept it

Comment: @YonatanNir I've added an edit. Please, take note of the part about the Model Binding as you will most probably encounter this problem pretty soon.

Answer (score 10):

I was getting the same error after invoking the WEB API from .NET MVC.
As suggested by @zhulien, I have changed from `[FromBody]` to `[FromForm]` in WebAPI, it works fine for me.

.NET Core WebAPI method.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromForm] LoginModel loginInfo)
    { // JWT code here }
```

.Net Core MVC Action Method.

```
public async void InvokeLoginAPIAsync(string endPoint, string userName, string pwd)
    {
        configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
              .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
              .Build();
        baseUrl = configuration["Application:BaseAPI"] ?? throw new Exception("Unable to get the configuration with key Application:BaseAPI");

        string targetUrl = string.Format("{0}/{1}", baseUrl, endPoint);

        using (HttpClient deviceClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, targetUrl);

           var data = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("userName", userName),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", pwd)
            };

            request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(data);

            using (var response = await deviceClient.SendAsync(request))
            {
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    TempData["Response"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response.Content);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, @KingRaja. The trick was the `[FromForm]`; jQuery's AJAX content type is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" by default. Also had to use this in the AJAX call: `data: { "": myStringValue }`. If I sent a serialized object up and used a DTO to map to, `[FromBody]` worked fine. Not sure why this all is so painful :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `[FromForm]` attribute before each argument in the controller function.