# ASP.Net Core Web API: Unsupported Media Type on GET Request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net5

I just started learning asp.net MVC6 and trying to learn how things work in it. Currently, I'm using the .net 5.0.
So this is the WebAPI method and I just added a object parameter **weatherForecast** to it:

```
        [BindProperties(SupportsGet = true)]
    public class WeatherForecast
    {

        public int TemperatureC { get; set; }

        public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);

        public string Summary { get; set; }
    }

    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get(WeatherForecast weatherForecast)
        {
            var rng = new Random();
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
}
```

When I sent this method a GET request from a browser or even from a POSTMAN:

```
http://localhost:1382/WeatherForecast?TemperatureC=12&Summary=HelloWorld
```

It returns:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13",
    "title": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "status": 415,
    "traceId": "00-a556c5fbdce0748bf3c7bd0e3200e92-21f4bf6470b534d-00"
}
```

The funny thing is in PostMan if I add a JSON body with a GET request (just for testing) then this works fine without any error.
I read the Microsoft model binding documentation [Here the link][1] and it says:
**"By default, properties are not bound for HTTP GET requests"**
so we have to use an attribute **[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]** or **[BindProperties(SupportsGet = true)]** and even after using this attribute it still doesn't work.

So after digging down, I found an attribute **[FromQuery]** and after using this with the object parameter **weatherForecast** it starts working. But I want to know why it's not working without this attribute?

Normally in MVC5 if we don't specify any attribute with parameters like **[FromUri]** etc then the model binder automatically binds the parameters sent in the query string.

What am I missing here?
[1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0#targets

Comment: There is no such thing as ".NET Framework 5.0" - ".NET 5" is not a direct successor to the .NET Framework 4.x (and "ASP.NET MVC 5" _has nothing to do_ with ASP.NET for .NET 5.

Comment: What is the definition of `WeatherForecast`?

Comment: I suspect you do not understand how HTTP `GET` requests and query-string parameters work...

Comment: @Dai I've edited my question and added the definition of WeatherForecast.

Comment: try `public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get([FromQuery] int TemperatureC, [FromQuery] string summary)` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49741284/asp-net-core-fromquery-usage-and-url-format. Your function expects a Object from Type: WeatherForecast, but what you are passing via http get are two params as http query. afaik

Comment: Can you show your controller header too pls?

Comment: @Serge added...

Answer (score 0):

You just have problems with routing values. You are using MVC routing but trying to add query string too. I suspect that your url hits a wrong action.

Since I can't  see your controller, I can only recommend to add  an attribute routing as the most reliable routing

```
    [Route("~/WeatherForecast/Get")]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get(WeatherForecast weatherForecast)
```

and use this url

```
http://localhost:1382/WeatherForecast/Get?TemperatureC=12&Summary=HelloWorld
```

Update

Since you posted your controller, I recommed you to remove  [Route("[controller]")] attribute, or if your startup config doesn't allow to do this change it to

```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]/[action]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
```

or for APIs usually

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
```

in this case you don't need  attribute routing , but your urls pattern should be

```
http://localhost:1382/WeatherForecast/<action>
//or
http://localhost:1382/api/WeatherForecast/<action> //if api added
```

and forget about REST, it is good for  a very simple textbook CRUDE only, in the real life each controller will have much more then 4 actions and you will not be able to find ehough gets and posts.